# Laravel Validation Multiple Files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to validate multi-select file uploads to Laravel.

I `print_r` my `Request` but I don't understand why it doesn't validate when clearly all uploads are images.

The `print_r` output:

> Array ( [file] => Array ( [0] => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object (
>   [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => 236x177_3F2.jpg [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => image/jpeg [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   19335
>   [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpWyxPrW
>   [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpWyxPrW ) [1] =>
>   Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object (
>   [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => Bierstadt_Sunrise_Lg_1966-1[1].jpg [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => image/jpeg [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   113765
>   [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/php5GtG4F
>   [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php5GtG4F ) ) )

The code:

```
if($typeof=="photo")
        {
        $photo = $request;
        print_r($photo::all());
        $validator = Validator::make($photo::all(), [
            'file' => 'required|image|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,bmp'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
           abort(500,"Not an image!");
        }
```

It always aborts with the not an image error, even though you can see from the `print_r` output that they are images.

Looks like a nested array I tried to offset my validation request and then I got undefined offset, please assist me to get to the actual file data for proper validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's not an image, it's an array of images.

You need to validate like this:

```
if($typeof=="photo")
{
    $photo = $request;
    print_r($photo::all());

    $validator = Validator::make($photo::all(), [
        'file.*' => 'required|image|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,bmp'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
       abort(500,"Not an image!");
    }
}
```